# how to give text area id of asp control to the jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a text area control and two text boxes in my web page. How do I pass the text area's and text boxes' ids into the jquery function?

```
<textarea id="jToolsProperties_htmlbox1" runat="server"></textarea>     
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="posStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="posEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

$(function () {
    $("#" + "<%=jToolsProperties_htmlbox1.ClientID%>").on("keyup click", function (e) {
        var pos = getCursorPos(this);
        alert(pos.start);
        alert(pos.end);
        $(this).siblings(".posStart").val(pos.start);
        $(this).siblings(".posEnd").val(pos.end);

    }).siblings("input").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).siblings("button").click();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        var par = $(this).parent();

        setCursorPos(par.find("#" + "<%=jToolsProperties_htmlbox1.ClientID%>")[0], +par.find(".posStart").val(), +par.find(".posEnd").val());

    });
});
```

Comment: it is in the same page

Comment: I can see that you are passing the client id. Isn't that working? What  do you see when you view the html source of the page after it is rendered in the browser? Is it correctly setting the client id as expected into the javascript?

Comment: Check the View source of generated HTML and get the ID. If you are not going to change the Master page Content placeholder Id, there is no harm in doing like this.

Comment: i checked the view source of generated html ., the two text boxes id's are <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$posStart" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_posStart" />
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$posEnd" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_posEnd" />
                            
and text area id is ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_jToolsProperties_htmlbox1 , plz help how to give the id's to above jquery function

Comment: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_jToolsProperties_htmlbox1") gets you the instance of the textarea. This should be same as  $("#" + "<%=jToolsProperties_htmlbox1.ClientID%>") as you have written. Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Please, paste the HTML generated including javascript code.

As quick workaround assign a css class to textarea and use it on your js code.

```
<textarea ... class="mytextarea" ...>

$(function () {
    $(".mytextarea").on("keyup click", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`$("#<%=jToolsProperties_htmlbox1.ClientID%>").on(...);`

It should work, i have tried this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your server side ID.

```
var name = "<%=jToolsProperties_htmlbox1.ClientID%>";
$find(name);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: on rendering id is modified asp.net render engine

Comment: Sorry @EhsanSajjad, My bad, I forgot that, as I remembered last working on MVC